# Is it possible to add personalized column to CPLEX Optimizer Node Log?

Tags: optimization, cplex

**IBM CPLEX** includes the following eight columns on the Optimizer Node Log:

1. Node  2. Nodes Left  3. Objective  4. IInf  5. Best Integer   6. Cuts/Best Node    7. ItCnt 8. Gap

I must admit they offer interesting basic information describing the optimization process. However, I would find convenient to show a CPU elapsed time column as well as a couple of relevant problem-specific information that would give me a better understanding of the optimization process during computation.

Nowhere I have been able to find information on how to personalize the Optimizer Node Log, only **IBM** tutorials on how to *read* the information presented on it. So, is it even possible to add custom columns to the CPLEX Optimizer Node Log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically no,  I think. But you can achieve something like this using a call back function from cplex.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more @TimChippingtonDerrick ? I'm new in C++. I'm using Callbacks but for adding Lazy Constraints, how could I add a column to the Optimizer Node Log via a Callback? Could you *give a reference* or *edit your answer to include a small example* please?

Comment: Not adding to the node log, but replicating similar output. If you use a node callback, it will get called at every node of the B&B tree. Inside the callback, print out the number of nodes explored, best bound, best integer solution found so far, current gap, etc as per the usual node log stuff, and add anything else that you want. There is a C++ example in the CPLEX install folder called iloadmipex1.cpp which uses a node callback, but not for printing stuff. You probably also want to only print out your info every 100 nodes or every 10 secs, so check for that inside the node callback too.